# python opencv sign recognition bitwise error

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I'm work in a project about sign recognition with *opencv*. In this script, I compare images of signals in my PC with image from my webcam.

but something is going wrong in the function `bitwise_xor`

error:

> The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::binary_op

my code is in here:
    (https://pastebin.com/bENGUY93)

thanks

Comment: Post your images.

Comment: images and script: http://www.mediafire.com/file/y8rx1yvm9uu53cy/code.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me. Just had to convert the `w/2` `floats` to `int`, that's it.

```
symbol[count].img = cv2.resize(image,(int(w/2),int(h/2)),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Comment: the code runs, but if you show a square to the webcam it's crash.

Comment: @MatheusMendes Post an image of a square that crashes the code.

Comment: open the arrow image in your phone, and test the code in your webcam.